# Можно (если да, то как) ли включить в Linux ядре механизм W^X?

Tags: linux, безопасность, ядро

Занимаюсь сборкой LFS с заточкой на безопасность (hardened сборка). Подскажите, можно ли вообще включить в Linux (хотя бы сторонними патчами) механизм W^X (write xor execute)? Насколько я знаю, этот прекрасный механизм по умолчанию включён в OpenBSD (кроме бинарников на файловых системах, смонтированных с опцией wxallowed) и может быть включён в FreeBSD некоторыми опциями ядра. Насколько я помню, это было в grsecurity патчах, но они проприетарные и платные: а есть ли свободные аналоги?

Comment: Вы имеете в виду, можно ли изменить сорсы ядра в плане установки rwx в таблицах трансляции или будет ли после такой правки работать основная масса applications?

Comment: можно ли изменить source ядра или же как либо иначе включить в ядре подобную опцию

Comment: Берите сорсы и меняйте. Только если вы это делаете не только для себя, то я не знаю механизмы утряски таких изменений со всем сообществом